# Python - Convert utf8 special characters (accented) to extended ascii equivalent

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii

I would like to use Python to convert utf8 special characters (accented, etc) to their extended ascii (purists are going to say there isn't such a thing, so here is a [link](https://www.asciitable.com/) to what I mean) equivalent.

So basically I want to read in a UTF-8 file and write out an extended ascii file (something like Latin-1 (I'm using windows) if that information is needed. I have read all the Unicode, etc. blogs and still don't understand a word of it), but I want to preserve as much of the information as possible. So for the UTF-8 character á I would like to convert it to the extended ascii equivalent á. I don't want to ignore or loose the character and I don't want to use an a. For characters where there is no equivalent extended ascii character I would just like to use a character of my choice such as ~, although some characters like ß I would like to convert to ss if there does not exist a ß in extended ascii.

Is there anything in Python 3 that can do this or can you give some example code of how I would do this?

Does anyone know of any site that lists the utf8 equivalents for the extended ascii characters?

Based on the comments below I have come up with this code, which sadly does not work very well since most of the special characters are returned as ? instead of ê (not sure why):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

f_in = open(r'E:/work/python/lyman.txt', 'rU', encoding='utf8')
raw = f_in.read()

f_out = open(r'E:/work/python/lyman_ascii.txt', 'w', encoding='cp1252', errors='replace')

retval = []
for char in raw:
    codepoint = ord(char)
    if codepoint < 0x80: # Basic ASCII
        retval.append(str(char))
        continue
    elif codepoint > 0xeffff:
        continue # Characters in Private Use Area and above are ignored
    # ë
    elif codepoint == 235:
        retval.append(chr(137))
        continue
    # ê
    elif codepoint == 234:
        retval.append(chr(136))
        continue
    # ’
    elif codepoint == 8217:
        retval.append(chr(39)) # 146 gives ? for some reason
        continue
    else:
        print(char)
        print(codepoint)

print(''.join(retval))
f_out.write(''.join(retval))
```

Comment: Do you mean [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850)?

Comment: Probably yeah. I use Windows and I'm from South Africa where we use United Kingdom English characters.

Comment: For wirting to a file in CP-850, use `open(filename, 'w', encoding='cp850', errors='replace')`; this will replace non-representable characters with "?". For converting 'ß' to 'ss' etc., you can use the thrid-party library [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/), but it will also replace "á" with "a" – the output is plain ASCII. If you want to combine both, you will need to build your own solution.

Comment: What you are suggesting is exactly what I don't want to do, hence my question about how to build my own solution.

Comment: Check how to simplify and remove accent. Then copy your tables in a editor (and get it as UTF-8, so with same visual representation). Then check: if the character is in that table, you use the cp-850 code in the table, else, you use the simplification of unicode (check other questions for this)

Comment: You should have a look at the [codec error handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers); there are more than just the `'replace'` one. Also, you can create and register your own handler, eg. one that uses "~" instead of "?", or something more fancy with like "ß"→"ss". As for the equivalence tables, I'm sure you'll find some in the source code of the unidecode library.

Comment: Sidenote: Never use `codecs.open`; consider it "virtually deprecated" (it exists largely to support some esoteric bytes->bytes/text->text codecs). On Python 2.7, use `io.open`, and on Python 3.x, use the built-in `open` (which is exactly the same as `io.open` on Python 3), both of which accept an `encoding` argument, and operate more efficiently and correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

# Don't use codecs in Python 3.
f_in = open(r'af_massaged.txt', 'rU', encoding='utf8')
raw = f_in.read()

f_out = open(r'af_massaged_ascii.txt', 'w', encoding='cp1252', errors='replace')

retval = []
for char in raw:
    codepoint = ord(char)
    if codepoint < 0x80:    # Basic ASCII.
        retval.append(str(char))
        continue
    elif codepoint > 0xeffff:
        continue    # Characters in Private Use Area and above are ignored.
    elif codepoint >= 128 and codepoint <= 159:
        continue    # Ignore control characters in Latin-1.
    # Don't use unichr in Python 3, chr uses unicode. Get character codes from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin-1_Supplement
    # This was written on Windows 7 32 bit
    # For 160 to 255 Latin-1 matches unicode.
    elif codepoint >= 160 and codepoint <= 255:
        retval.append(str(char))
        continue
    # –
    elif codepoint == 8211:
        retval.append(chr(45))
        continue
    # ’
    elif codepoint == 8217:
        retval.append(chr(180)) # 39
        continue
    # “
    elif codepoint == 8220:
        retval.append(chr(34))
        continue
    # ”
    elif codepoint == 8221:
        retval.append(chr(34))
        continue
    # €
    elif codepoint == 8364:
        retval.append('Euro')
        continue
    # Find missing mappings.
    else:
        print(char)
        print(codepoint)

# Uncomment for debugging.
#for i in range(128, 256):
#    retval.append(str(i) + ': ' + chr(i) + chr(13))

#print(''.join(retval))
f_out.write(''.join(retval))
```